# Lets Encrypt Setup failure

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt

-- My English skill is not enough --

1. I try setup Lets Encrypt on CentOS (VPS fixed IP Address)
   -> It Success!
2. I try setup Let's encrypt on Debian (No fixed IP Address and in house server)
   -> It Failed
3. I try --manual mode with this command

   ```
   ./letsencrypt-auto certonly --manual -d #MY-DOMAIN# --server HTTPS://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
   ```

and that command say put key file.
Random strings Displayed. FileName and Key Code. 2 Random string.

```
    http://#MY-DOMAIN#/.well-known/acme-challenge/#LONG-RANDOM-FILENAME#
```

4. Yes I do save that key domain document root.

   /Path to/My-Domain/Doc Root/.well-known/acme-challenge/#LONG-RANDOM-FILENAME#

5.Check file by other network.
Access http://#MY-DOMAIN#/.well-known/acme-challenge/#LONG-RANDOM-FILENAME#
-> It Success!

6.Continue Lets Encrypt setup. but...

```
IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: #MY-DOMAIN#
   Type:   connection
   Detail: Could not connect to
   http://#MY-DOMAIN#/.well-known/acme-challenge/#LONG-RANDOM-FILENAME#

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address. Additionally, please check that
   your computer has a publicly routable IP address and that no
   firewalls are preventing the server from communicating with the
   client. If you're using the webroot plugin, you should also verify
   that you are serving files from the webroot path you provided.
```

He say error.could not connect my server.
but my domain is published.

and Check DNS by Dig command

```
   ;; QUESTION SECTION:
   ;#MY-DOMAIN#.                    IN      A

   ;; ANSWER SECTION:
   #MY-DOMAIN#.             120     IN      A       #MY-SERVER-IPADDR#
```

My house Server IP Address is fixed by 2 month ago.
and Apache Logfile is not include access log.
Why Lets Encrypt server cant watch my server?